# Implementing link in PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to implement links in my foreach loop. However, can't get the $category link working. Any pointers? Managed to get the link to work for the sub-category, as shown below:

```
<?
$output = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM bikes, bikeTypes WHERE bikes.model_id = bikeTypes.model_id");
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($output))
{
   $result[$row['model']][] = $row;
}

foreach ($result as $category => $values) {
  echo "<li>".$category.'<ul>';
    foreach ($values as $value) {
      echo "<a href='details.php?id=" . $row['model_id'] . "'><li>" . $value['bikeName'] . "</a></li>";
    }
echo '</ul>';   
echo '</li>';
}
?>
```

Thanks for the help in advance guys! :)

Comment: the website concerned is http://www.mattmaclennan.co.uk/a2 if that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML Tags are not in the correct order first commes the li-tag and then the a-tag

```
  foreach ($values as $value) {
      echo "<li><a href='details.php?id=" . $row['model_id'] . "'>" . $value['bikeName'] . "</a></li>";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `a` and `li` tags are intertwined:

```
<a><li>...</a></li>
```

this should be:

```
<li><a>...</a></li>
```