# In mysql togher with html is recorded php variable. Want to fetch all and treat the php variable as variable, not html

Tags: php, mysql

If I open php file I can write for example

```
Start text 
<?php $var='array from mysql'; 
echo $var;?>. 
Continue text
```

As result I will see `Start text array from mysql. Continue text`

Want to do the same with mysql. But get `Start text <?php $var='array from mysql'; echo $var;?>. Continue text`

How fetch data from mysql and treat php variables as variables? Is it safe?

I need all this because in one page want to show text and list of links. List of links will be dynamic (I will write pages and number of links will increase). So not to manually add all new links, want to fetch link-url from mysql. And list of links want to show in certain place in page. Possibly there is other simple solution, but at the moment do not know other solution

The same is with hyperlink. If in mysql record `<a href="topic">Topic name</a>` then php echo exactly what is recorded in mysql and not hyperlink.

Full code would be very long. But here is some short (paste modified code)

```
 $_POST['topic_url'] = '<a href="topic">Topic name</a>';
 //or
 $_POST['topic_url'] = '<?php $var="array from mysql"; echo $var; ?>';
```

Record in mysql

```
 $stmt_insert = $db->prepare( 'INSERT INTO topics ( TopicUrl ) VALUES (?) ;' );
 $stmt_insert->execute( array( $_POST['topic_url'] ) );
```

In mysql varchar field i have `<a href="topic">Topic name</a>`

then fetch

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT TopicUrl FROM topics");
 $stmt->execute();
 $content = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

then echo simply

```
 echo htmlspecialchars( $content['TopicUrl'] , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

and in web page see the same `<a href="topic">Topic name</a>`

but want to see hyperlink, named Topic name

If `echo $content['MainText'];` then can see hyperlink. But if instead of hyperlink, in mysql record this

```
<?php $var="array from mysql"; 
echo $var;
?>
```

and echo, then see nothing.

Comment: The best solution would be to design your database properly. You could put a list of links into one table and articles into another. The attributes for the links table might be as follows: `link_id`, `link_name`, `anchor`, `target`. Then you can just generate the necessary `(X)HTML` by combining variables with values fetched from the database and plain `(X)HTML`.

Comment: yes u can and its safe but the parent page should be PHP , for example inside `index.php`  parse Sql variables and then include index.html , inside `index.html` use php tags to print out the variables `<a href="
<?php echo $row['link'] ?>">here link</a>`

Comment: But how to 'tell' that I want to see hyperlinks in certain place of a page? If a page contains just hyperlinks, then seems easy (fetch and using foreach echo what is necessary). I want to write text in mysql and in certain place of the text tell php that here i want to see hyperlinks (hyperlinks already fetched from mysql as array; just want to print_r the array in certain place)

Comment: do you have full code of what u tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a couple issues here.  To render html properly in php, you need to include the header, html, and body tags.  If you add those around your code, the hyperlink should render properly in the browser.

The other main issue I see is you should store the url and name of each entry separately in the database.  The html portion should not be in the db.  You can use a php function to wrap each row, but certainly don't store the full html line like that.  Do yourself a favor for the future and study up on database design including 3rd normal form.

[Formatting info](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/5)

Comment: Thanks, will check all. But question remains. How to 'tell' php that in certain place (in the middle of text) I want to see list of links (fetched array from mysql)

Comment: See this similar question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147916/implementing-link-in-php-foreach-loop]